# Java - Return correct type from Generic method

Tags: java, generics, class-design, return-type

I have the following class structure:

```
public class Team {
    ...
}

public class Event {

}

public abstract class Fixture<T extends Team> implements Event {
   ...
}

public abstract class Forecast<Event> {

}

public class MyPrediction<T extends Fixture<? extends Team>> extends Forecast<Fixture<? extends Team>>{

}
```

I am trying to model sports events of all kinds (i.e. a 'Fixture' is for a particular game between two participants play against each other, whereas another type of 'Event' may have many participants), along with predictions for the outcome of particular 'Events'. I have a generic method:

```
public <T> MyPrediction<Fixture<? extends Team>> getMyPrediction(Fixture<? extends Team> fixture) {
```

}

I want to be able to return a `MyPrediction` instance which has the generic type of the `fixture` argument, but I can't seem to do so. For example, if I do something like the following, then I get a compilation error:

```
SoccerFixture<EnglishSoccerTeams> soccerMatch = new ScoccerFixture<EnglishSoccerTeams>();
MyPrediction<SoccerFixture<EnglishSoccerTeams>> = getMyPrediction(soccerMatch);
```

I am willing to change my class structure to incorporate this feature. How can I do so?

Comment: "If I do something like the following" ... then (what problem do you encounter)?

Comment: it looks like Event needs to be an interface

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the signature of `getMyPrediction` to

```
public <T extends Fixture<? extends Team>> MyPrediction<T> getMyPrediction(T fixture)
```

This tells the compiler that the fixture types in the argument and result are the same, allowing type-checking to pass.

Here is a complete example, with some other minor changes to get it to compile.  It introduces the class `Predictor` to hold the `getMyPrediction` method and a `doit` method to show sample use:

```
public interface Team {
}

public interface Event {
}

public abstract class Fixture<T extends Team> implements Event {
}

public abstract class Forecast<T> {
}

public class MyPrediction<T extends Fixture<? extends Team>> extends
        Forecast<Fixture<? extends Team>> {
}

public class SoccerFixture<T extends SoccerTeam> extends Fixture<T> {
}

public class SoccerTeam implements Team {
}

public class EnglishSoccerTeam extends SoccerTeam {
}

public class Predictor {

    public <T extends Fixture<? extends Team>> MyPrediction<T> getMyPrediction(T fixture) {
        return new MyPrediction<T>();
    }

    public void doit() {
        SoccerFixture<EnglishSoccerTeam> soccerMatch = new SoccerFixture<EnglishSoccerTeam>();
        MyPrediction<SoccerFixture<EnglishSoccerTeam>> myPrediction = getMyPrediction(soccerMatch);
    }
}
```

As noted elsewhere, you might need to introduce one or more factory objects to perform meaningful work in the `MyPrediction` implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Java's type system is not powerful enough to do directly what you propose, because of type erasure (the generic parameters are not available at runtime.

The usual solution is to create a separate EventFactory class, which you can then pass in to any method which needs to create a specific Event subtype instance.